# Error: write EIO error while yarn install of CRA application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, create-react-app, yarnpkg

I have the latest version of `node` installed `v12.6.0`. The React.js is `v16.8.1`. `yarn` is also the latest `v1.17.3`.
Today I deleted the `node_modules` directory from my React app which I created using `create-react-app`. To download the latest dependencies I fired `yarn install` on my project using Terminal and installation started. Now, for the first time, I saw error logs while installing the packages and a `yarn-error.log` file also got generated.

I have no clue how this suddenly came up. Googled it, didn't find exact issue but some recommended to upgrade the `node`. But mine is already latest.

Since there are lots of logs written, I am pasting here the top most lines with the error.

```
Arguments: 
  /usr/local/Cellar/node/12.6.0/bin/node /usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.17.3/libexec/bin/yarn.js start

PATH: 
  /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Work/Git Repo/Code/FrontEnd/my-website/node_modules/.bin:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_172.jdk/Contents/Home/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Work/Git Repo/Code/FrontEnd/my-website/node_modules/.bin:/Work/Apache/apache-maven-3.5.2/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Work/my-website/Git Repo/Code/FrontEnd/my-website/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin

Yarn version: 
  1.17.3

Node version: 
  12.6.0

Platform: 
  darwin x64

Trace: 
  Error: write EIO
      at afterWriteDispatched (internal/stream_base_commons.js:146:25)
      at writeGeneric (internal/stream_base_commons.js:137:3)
      at WriteStream.Socket._writeGeneric (net.js:698:11)
      at WriteStream.Socket._write (net.js:710:8)
      at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:417:12)
      at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:401:5)
      at WriteStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:301:11)
      at Object.clearLine (readline.js:1248:12)
      at clearLine (/usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.17.3/libexec/lib/cli.js:49621:12)
      at ConsoleReporter._log (/usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.17.3/libexec/lib/cli.js:96496:43)

npm manifest: 
  {
    "name": "my-website",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
      "anchorme": "^1.1.2",
      "axios": "^0.18.0",
      "connected-react-router": "^6.4.0",
      "formik": "^1.5.2",
      "lodash": "^4.17.11",
      "react": "^16.8.1",
      "react-animations": "^1.0.0",
      "react-datepicker": "^2.5.0",
      "react-dom": "^16.8.1",
      "react-helmet": "^5.2.0",
      "react-pdf": "^4.0.2",
      "react-redux": "^6.0.0",
      "react-router-dom": "^5.0.0",
      "react-scripts": "2.0.5",
      "react-transition-group": "^2.6.0",
      "reaptcha": "^1.4.2",
      "redux": "^4.0.1",
      "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
      "redux-saga": "^0.16.2",
      "semantic-ui-css": "^2.4.1",
      "semantic-ui-react": "^0.82.5",
      "styled-components": "^4.1.3",
      "yup": "^0.27.0",
      "prop-types": "latest"
    },
    "scripts": {
      "start": "PORT=3007 react-scripts start",
      "build": "react-scripts build",
      "test": "react-scripts test",
      "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
      "extends": "react-app",
      "rules": {
        "jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid": 0
      }
    },
    "browserslist": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not ie <= 11",
      "not op_mini all"
    ]
  }

yarn manifest: 
  No manifest

Lockfile: 
  # THIS IS AN AUTOGENERATED FILE. DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE DIRECTLY.
  # yarn lockfile v1


  "@babel/code-frame@7.0.0", "@babel/code-frame@^7.0.0", "@babel/code-frame@^7.0.0-beta.35":
    version "7.0.0"
    resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@babel/code-frame/-/code-frame-7.0.0.tgz#06e2ab19bdb535385559aabb5ba59729482800f8"
    dependencies:
      "@babel/highlight" "^7.0.0"

  "@babel/core@7.1.0":
    version "7.1.0"
    resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@babel/core/-/core-7.1.0.tgz#08958f1371179f62df6966d8a614003d11faeb04"
    dependencies:
      "@babel/code-frame" "^7.0.0"
      "@babel/generator" "^7.0.0"
      "@babel/helpers" "^7.1.0"
      "@babel/parser" "^7.1.0"
      "@babel/template" "^7.1.0"
      "@babel/traverse" "^7.1.0"
      "@babel/types" "^7.0.0"
      convert-source-map "^1.1.0"
      debug "^3.1.0"
      json5 "^0.5.0"
      lodash "^4.17.10"
      resolve "^1.3.2"
      semver "^5.4.1"
      source-map "^0.5.0"

  "@babel/core@^7.0.1":
    version "7.4.0"
    resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@babel/core/-/core-7.4.0.tgz#248fd6874b7d755010bfe61f557461d4f446d9e9"
    dependencies:
      "@babel/code-frame" "^7.0.0"
      "@babel/generator" "^7.4.0"
      "@babel/helpers" "^7.4.0"
      "@babel/parser" "^7.4.0"
      "@babel/template" "^7.4.0
   .........................
   .......................
```

The logs from Terminal:

```
yarn install v1.17.3
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
[3/4]   Linking dependencies...
[4/4]   Building fresh packages...
[-/4] ⢀ waiting...
[2/4] ⠠ fsevents
[3/4] ⠠ fsevents
warning Error running install script for optional dependency: "/Work/my-website/Git Repo/Code/FrontEnd/my-website/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/fsevents: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: node install
Arguments: 
Directory: /Work/my-website/Git Repo/Code/FrontEnd/my-website/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/fsevents
Output:
node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@0.10.0
node-pre-gyp info using node@12.6.0 | darwin | x64
node-pre-gyp info check checked for \"/Work/my-website/Git Repo/Code/FrontEnd/my-website/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64/fse.node\" (not found)
node-pre-gyp http GET https://fsevents-binaries.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1.2.4/fse-v1.2.4-node-v72-darwin-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp http 404 https://fsevents-binaries.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1.2.4/fse-v1.2.4-node-v72-darwin-x64.tar.gz
node-pre-gyp WARN Tried to download(404): https://fsevents-binaries.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1.2.4/fse-v1.2.4-node-v72-darwin-x64.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not found for fsevents@1.2.4 and node@12.6.0 (node-v72 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
node-pre-gyp http 404 status code downloading tarball https://fsevents-binaries.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1.2.4/fse-v1.2.4-node-v72-darwin-x64.tar.gz 
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@12.6.0 | darwin | x64
gyp info ok 
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@12.6.0 | darwin | x64
gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python
gyp info spawn args [
gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/Cellar/node/12.6.0/libexec/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-f',
gyp info spawn args   'make',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Work/my-website/Git Repo/Code/FrontEnd/my-website/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/fsevents/build/config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/Cellar/node/12.6.0/libexec/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-I',
gyp info spawn args   '/Users/pusp/.node-gyp/12.6.0/include/node/common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/pusp/.node-gyp/12.6.0',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/usr/local/Cellar/node/12.6.0/libexec/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/pusp/.node-gyp/12.6.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Work/my-website/Git Repo/Code/FrontEnd/my-website/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/fsevents',
gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args   'build',
gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
gyp info spawn args ]
gyp info ok 
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@12.6.0 | darwin | x64
gyp info spawn make
gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/.node
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/fse/fsevents.o
../fsevents.cc:50:32: error: no template named 'Handle' in namespace 'v8'
    static void Initialize(v8::Handle<v8::Object> exports);
                           ~~~~^
../fsevents.cc:63:6: warning: field 'async_resource' will be initialized after field 'lockStarted' [-Wreorder]
   : async_resource(\"fsevents:FSEvents\"), lockStarted(false) {
     ^
In file included from ../fsevents.cc:82:
../src/constants.cc:89:11: warning: 'Set' is deprecated: Use maybe version [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  object->Set(Nan::New<v8::String>(\"kFSEventStreamEventFlagNone\").ToLocalChecked(), Nan::New<v8::Integer>(kFSEventStreamEventFlagNone));
          ^
/Users/pusp/.node-gyp/12.6.0/include/node/v8.h:3358:3: note: 'Set' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
  V8_DEPRECATE_SOON(\"Use maybe version\",
  ^
/Users/pusp/.node-gyp/12.6.0/include/node/v8config.h:326:29: note: expanded from macro 'V8_DEPRECATE_SOON'
  declarator __attribute__((deprecated(message)))
...........................
...........................
stackgyp     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:272:12)
 ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:272:12)
gyp ERR! Systemgyp Darwin 17.7.0
 ERR! System Darwin 17.7.0
gyp ERR! gypcommand  \"/usr/local/Cellar/node/12.6.0/bin/node\" \"/usr/local/Cellar/node/12.6.0/libexec/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js\" \"build\" \"--fallback-to-build\" \"--module=/Work/my-website/Git Repo/Code/FrontEnd/my-website/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64/fse.node\" \"--module_name=fse\" \"--module_path=/Work/my-website/Git Repo/Code/FrontEnd/my-website/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64\" \"--napi_version=4\" \"--node_abi_napi=napi\"
ERR!gyp  ERR!command  \"/usr/local/Cellar/node/12.6.0/bin/node\" \"/usr/local/Cellar/node/12.6.0/libexec/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js\" \"build\" \"--fallback-to-build\" \"--module=/Work/my-website/Git Repo/Code/FrontEnd/my-website/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64/fse.node\" \"--module_name=fse\" \"--module_path=/Work/my-website/Git Repo/Code/FrontEnd/my-website/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64\" \"--napi_version=4\" \"--node_abi_napi=napi\"
cwdgyp ERR! cwd /Work/my-website/Git Repo/Code/FrontEnd/my-website/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v12.6.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
 /Work/my-website/Git Repo/Code/FrontEnd/my-website/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v12.6.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'node-gyp build --fallback-to-build --module=/Work/my-website/Git Repo/Code/FrontEnd/my-website/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64/fse.node --module_name=fse --module_path=/Work/my-website/Git Repo/Code/FrontEnd/my-website/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v72-darwin-x64 --napi_version=4 --node_abi_napi=napi' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Work/my-website/Git Repo/Code/FrontEnd/my-website/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:203:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 17.7.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! command \"/usr/local/Cellar/node/12.6.0/bin/node\" \"/Work/my-website/Git Repo/Code/FrontEnd/my-website/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/bin/node-pre-gyp\" \"install\" \"--fallback-to-build\"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /Work/my-website/Git Repo/Code/FrontEnd/my-website/node_modules/fsevents
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v12.6.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.10.3
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
success Saved lockfile.
✨  Done in 38.28s.
```

I tried `yarn cache clean && yarn` also but not helpful.

Comment: I solved it by creating a fresh CRA project which used latest version of React

Answer (score 0):

I re-installed the xcode tools and it helped:

```
sudo rm -rf $(xcode-select -print-path)
xcode-select --install
```